# i am using .net window application . i need to make my form UI better. how to do that?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

i am using .net window application . i need to make my form UI better. how to do that?

Is there any predefined shins available?...

I am new in this suggest any good idea...

Comment: i would make my winform like a vista style form...w

Comment: I have two shins that are predefined.

Comment: When your WinForm runs in Vista, it will be a Vista-style form.  If you want it to look like Vista in other versions of Windows, it would be handled just like any custom skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/).

Answer (score 1):

With WinForms you only fairly basic control.  You can set colors, transparency, font, etc. on controls.  You can also set a background image and specify one color as the transparency mask (see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/splforms.aspx).

If you want more advanced features you'll probably want to look into a 3rd party solution (e.g. http://www.sunisoft.com/irisskin/), but most are still fairly limited.

If you want a **very** flexible solution, I suggest looking into WPF (examples: http://navajocoder.com/, http://familyshow.codeplex.com/, [What real world WPF applications are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837/what-real-world-wpf-applications-are-out-there), http://adamkinney.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/357/, etc.) or Silverlight, both built on the same technology and part of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Microsoft UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511440.aspx) design guidelines will get you a good way to getting a decent user interface, without any skins required.